# Delay during disk writes when logging data

Tags: c++, linux, raspbian

I'm currently running raspbian on a raspberry pi, within which I'm running an application that is sampling raw data at 400Hz from a sensor and logging it to a file. My problem is that the program hangs for around 500ms to 1s every 10-15 seconds, due to some internal buffer writing to the SD card.

I've tried setting the buffer to 0 using the following code, but this doesn't seem to have made any difference, and neither during using flush()

```
std::fstream Log;
Log.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(0, 0);
```

I'm assuming this problem is being caused by something in the kernel as opposed to my application, but I have no idea where to start looking. An explanation of where my problem most likely lies would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Matt

Comment: What is the actual amount of data being written to the file per second?

Comment: I see it typically due to buffering in the OS when writing to files on the disk. I use `flush` after every write. Lookup `stdbuf`, it may become useful.

Comment: @Aater I was thinking about that too, but with a stream of data being written at a constant rate, dirty pages would expire continuously, right? Shouldn't that result in more frequent, but shorter hangs, instead of 1s every 10s?

Comment: @us2012, 68kb/s at the moment, although this does vary by say +-20%

Comment: @Matthew That's not a lot at all. Even the cheapest SD cards out there should handle that *easily*. Are you sure that your hangs are due to buffers/writing out data?

Comment: @us2012 The disk controller activity light is on for the exact duration of each hang, so I assume this is the cause.

Comment: @Matthew Are you planning to let this run 24/7 or does this run only minutes at a time? If it's the latter, why not put all data in a binary stream in memory and only write it out after you have obtained all samples you need? You should at least try this as it will show whether the problem is due to storage.

Comment: @us2012 Here is a matlab plot of sample time against time, showing multiple 200-300ms delays and one large 1.6s one: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2i09geq&s=6

As for the writing it to memory, I have considered this, but the application often cannot be stopped gracefully, meaning it won't know when to write out its buffer before the power is lost. I will try this however to see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the linux `pdflush` tunables: [http://www.westnet.com/~gsmith/content/linux-pdflush.htm](http://web.archive.org/web/20150310033505/http://www.westnet.com/%7Egsmith/content/linux-pdflush.htm)

The first thing I would try is making pages expire sooner, e.g. set `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centiseconds` to `500`. If that does not work, decrease `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs` and `dirty_expire_centiseconds` along with it.

Note that in general, this may *decrease* the overall performance of your system - the aggressive caching is there for a reason. In your case though, this might help by making the writes more regular.

Comment: Well through examining meminfo I can see the delays definitely occur at the same time as the 'dirty' section empties.

Comment: @Matthew So, does decreasing those two values help? (I wouldn't go below 100, but 100 (1 second) may be worth trying.)

Comment: Changing the two expiry times doesn't seem to have any effect, which I expected given that the period between delays doesn't match either of the two values. I'll keep trying playing with the other parameters and see if I get anywhere. Also, I tried calling sync() after every log write (so at 400Hz), but the overhead from this completely killed the app. I'm beginning to think logging to memory might be the better idea after all.

Comment: @Matthew Try `fsync()` on the file descriptor of your file, but don't do it at 400Hz, but at 1 or 2 Hz (you probably have a sample counter already - sync when `counter % 400 == 0`.)

Comment: Since I'm using an ostream I don't believe I can access the file descriptor to use fsync. I tried using sync(), but again just the overhead itself posed too great of a delay.

Comment: Unless your file logic is very complicated, I would try switching to old fashioned C I/O to get the file descriptors and try the once-a-second-sync I described above. Alternatively (especially if it turns out that this is a hardware bottleneck, e.g. another hardware buffer in the SD controller), is it an option to use LAN/WLAN (I'm talking low-level - raw via sockets - instead of samba/nfs here as those 'suffer' from the VFS caches, too) instead of local SD for storage.